# How do I filter and view daily logs in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an express API application running on GAE. It is my understanding that every time someone makes a GET request to it, it creates a log. In the Logs Explorer (Operations -> Logging -> Logs Explorer), I can filter to view only GET requests from a certain source by querying:

```
protoPayload.method="GET"
protoPayload.referrer="https://fakewebsite.com/"
```

In the top-right of the Logs Explorer, I can also select a time range of 1 day to view logs from the past 24 hours.

I want to be able to see how many GET requests the app receives from a given referrer every day. Is this possible? And is there functionality to display the daily logs in a bar chart (say, to easily visualize how many logs I get every day over the period of a week)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this but not directly in the Cloud Logging service. You have started well: you have created a custom filter.

Then, create a sink and save the logs to BigQuery.

So now, you can perform a query to count the GET every day, and you can build a datastudio dashboard to visualise your logs.

Answer (score 0):

If only the count is needed on daily basis you can create a sink to stream data directly into the BigQuery. As the data needs to be segregated on daily basis while creating a sink , a better option would be to use a partition table which can help you in two ways:

- You would have a new table everyday
- Based on your usage although BigQuery provide a free tier , this data is not
  needed in near future storing it this way will reduce your cost and querying cost

BigQuery comes with data studio , as soon as you query on table you'll have the option to explore the result in Data studio and generate reports as needed.

[image: Explore Data Option]